# Can we classify a pointer as built-in datatype in data structure?

Tags: pointers, data-structures

**BUILT-IN DATATYPES IN DATA STRUCTURES**
How can we classify pointer as datatype ?
I want to ask that how a pointer can be classified as built-in datatype in data structure.

Comment: We can define terms however we want, it depends on the context. What are you trying to accomplish/convey by defining pointers as a built-in data structure? You are using the terms "datatype" and "data structure", what do these terms mean to you? What does it mean to be "built-in" in this context?

Comment: By terms "datatype" and "data structure" , I mean that " datatypes in data structures".  "Built-in" refers to "defined datatypes in data structures". I simply need to ask that pointers can be classified in datatypes ? If yes, then which type of datatype - built-in or user-defined.